# It it possible to use apps for mobile?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

It is said that mobile OS Android is originated from Linux.

It the statement true? And Can I use apps built for Android OS in Ubuntu?

Thank you.

HELLOVENUS Fantagio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. Android even uses different processor architecture(except some tablets with Intel x86 processors).
Even the kernel is heavily modified.

You can install Android-x86 on QEMU/VirtualBox to run part of the mobile apps working with the x86 architecture.